# Removal of arm from Saguaro Cactus

Tags: diagnosis

I have a cactus and one of the arms is on my house and I want to remove the arm. It is not big and will not throw off the balance of the cactus. What I am wondering is will the cactus heal and are there any precautions I should take or put anything on the cactus after removing the arm

Comment: It always helps to provide a photo of the plant in question.

Comment: Welcome Treegirl. It's nice to meet you! As @GrahamChiu said, no matter what question you have, pictures are important, and sometimes they're the only way to get the answer you need. Also, we could use more details (as described on the [ask] page of our [help]). I'm not sure what you mean by on your house? Is it inside our out? Is it up against a wall and the arm is just in the way, or does either the plant or that arm look sick? If you need any help using the site, leave us a note right here. Have fun!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear what you're asking. If you return and edit it by adding pictures and detail, we'll gladly take another look at it!